# admob is undefined using PhoneGap plugin?

Tags: android, cordova, admob, phonegap-plugins

I'm using a PhoneGap plugin (https://github.com/aliokan/cordova-plugin-admob) to serve ads in my app.

However, I keep getting an error stating that admob is not defined (admob being the primary object provided by the plugin). I've already ran `phonegap build android` but the error is still present.

How can I get PhoneGap to recognize the plugin and load the required JavaScript?

Comment: I don't recommend you to use this plugin, it is based on the [GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar](https://github.com/aliokan/cordova-plugin-admob/tree/master/src/android/libs) *August.Deprecated. On August 1, 2014, Google Play will stop accepting new or updated apps that use the old standalone Google Mobile Ads SDK v6.4.1 or lower*

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably caused by cordova v3.4, not the plugin.

Log pasted:

```
03-25 18:21:03.810: D/PluginManager(7273): exec() call to unknown plugin: AdMob
03-25 18:21:03.930: D/GLWebViewState(7273): Reinit transferQueue
```

finally, it's resolved by downgrade v3.4 to v3.3.

As the defect is fixed in v3.5, it's a better choice to upgrade to v3.5 or later.